# How can I disable i915 Intel integrated graphics permanently?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, intel-graphics, integrated

I have a nVidia GTX660 running the latest drivers via the Ubuntu additional hardware tab. As such, I noticed I have been having weird issues when playing graphic intensive games and I found that people with my setup have an issue with the integrated graphics and they said they noticed better performance after 'blacklisting' them.

My question: How can I blacklist the i915 Intel integrated graphics driver? And would this cause any problems?

Thank you.

Comment: The Ubuntu additional hardware tab is not known for updated drivers, unless you've added the xorg-edgers ppa. Please state your driver and system version/name.

Comment: 14.04.02 LTS, using an alienware x51 rig with 2x 4gb DDR3 dual channel, intel i7-3770, and 1TB seagate harddrive @7200rpm and an nvidia gtx660

Comment: And the nvidia driver?

Comment: NVIDIA binary driver 331.113 from nvidia-331(proprietary, tested)

Answer (score -1):

Logout your session, open a tty.

Stop the graphic session service. On Ubuntu is `lightdm`, Gnome is `gdm`, Mint is `mdn`. No need to type what’s after the `#` it's just a comment.

```
sudo service stop lightdm  #Change service accordingly
sudo apt-get purge nvidia* bumblebee primus #Delete all nvidia installed libs
sudo apt-get autoremove    #Delete unneeded packages
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-settings ppa-purge #Install new nvidia driver
```

Reboot your machine, if everything is ok login open 'NVIDIA Settings' a choose which GPU you prefer. Unfortunately `bumblebee` isn't working with this driver version or I'm still to find a way to make it work. In your case it's what you've asked only one GPU will be activated.

If no graphic session is started you'll have to remove the driver.

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-346
```

Reboot again, `nouveau` will take over, reinstall previous drivers.